# SQL Azure Federations - Development Environment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, federation

My team development environment is based on local databases (SQL Server) and now I need to move our application to be based on SQL Azure Federations.
There's any way to "emulate" SQL Azure Federations in a local environment? Or should our development environment change?

Comment: Not stacks of info but take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878215/emulate-simulate-sql-azure-locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

afaik, you can't.

while you can simulate partitioning of data on your local SQL Server in terms of where they get stored  (e.g, table partitions or partitioned views), you can't simulate the FEDERATION statements (i.e., USE FEDERATION, etc...) as they are only valid in Azure SQL Database Federations.